# How to build pkgdetails.c for debian?

Tags: debian

I'm just a newbie for debian, I want to build debian for sh4 arch.
When I run debbootstrap, it appears:

```
E: No pkgdetails available; either install perl, or build pkgdetails.c from source
```

I don't know where to download the pkgdetails.c, it seems already removed from debootstrap source.

The most similar code I found is [here](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/packages/utils/debootstrap/files/pkgdetails.c). But I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

If you install Perl somehow (and symlink `/usr/bin/perl`, if it isn't there), it should work.

In some very minimal environments, that might not be that easy. For me (on a QNAP), I had qpkg available and I could install qpkg packages via the admin webinterface. That allowed me to install ipkg, which is a common package manager which might be available for your system, too.

Via ipkg, you can install Perl (`ipkg install perl`). For the debootstrap script, you need to have `/usr/bin/perl` symlinked to your Perl installation, which might be `/opt/bin/perl`.

On my system, `ar` was also missing and needed for debootstrap. Via ipkg, you can install binutils, which contains that package (just to be sure, I again symlinked that to `/usr/bin/`).

Some helpful discussion (with the ipkg tips) was [here](http://smtp.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=20174&p=223728).